# InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: go, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I make project Go gin

I make send an SMS message for user phone number

When the implementation of the code is completed and the program is executed, the following error occurs

```
InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

I think the error course missing token.
but I don`t know get how to get token

this below my code

```
func PushSms(phoneNumber, code string) error {
    fmt.Println("create session")

    AccessKey := os.Getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY")
    SecretAccessKey := os.Getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")

    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region:      aws.String("ap-northeast-1"),
        Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials(AccessKey, SecretAccessKey, ""),
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    svc := sns.New(sess)

    input := &sns.PublishInput{
        Message:     aws.String("test" + code),
        PhoneNumber: aws.String(phoneNumber),
    }

    result, err := svc.Publish(input)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(result)

    return nil
}
```

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this issue change part of session.NewSession change code

```
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
      Region:      aws.String("ap-northeast-1"),
      Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials(AccessKey, SecretAccessKey, ""),
})
```

to

```
.env
AWS_ACCESS_KEY=access_key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret_access_key
AWS_REGION=ap-northeast-1


sess, err := session.NewSession()
```

thanks